# Pyspark/python chinese characters not recognized

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, encode, python-unicode

Sorry I know this question has been asked many times, but I really can't find a solution that could solve my problem.

I am using pyspark module in python to read a file:

```
data = sc.textFile("data/text_data.csv")
```

After some data cleaning, I get two columns, all of which are Chinese characters. However, the first three records look like below, where elements in the first tuple is the column name.

```
[('aybh_zw', 'jyaq'),
('������', '�ڶ��綫·�\U000ffd7c�\u0530�ſ�������������'),
('030', 'FF5E84D38B5B48CF97F26B5E6DAB4DD8')]
```

So I did this transformation next:

```
second_cleaned_data = first_cleaned_data.map(lambda s: (s[0].encode('UTF-8), s[1].encode('UTF-8'))
```

However, data becomes below:

```
[(b'aybh_zw', b'jyaq'),
(b'\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd',
(b'030', b'FF5E84D38B5B48CF97F26B5E6DAB4DD8')]
```

Where I omitted the second element in the second tuple due to some stackoverflow formatting issues.

Since this is still incorrect, I then did following and get:

```
[('aybh_zw', 'jyaq'),
('锟斤拷锟斤拷锟斤拷', '锟节讹拷锟界东路锟襟康硷拷园锟脚匡拷锟'),
('030', 'FF5E84D38B5B48CF97F26B5E6DAB4DD8')]
```

Still, this is incorrect since those characters are not what they should be.

So could anyone help me with this? I really don't know what to do.
Thank you

A sample of csv file is below:

```
recordkey   ajbh    ajjf    ajlx    ajlx_zw ajly    ajly_zw ajmc    ajzt    
QTIwMTUwNjAwMDFfMzcxNDAwMDE A2015060001 0   2   刑事  1   110指令   张俊杰被盗窃案 202 已立案 212000002   盗窃罪 盗窃罪 371499  经济  2.02E+13    东风路电业局宿舍    6/13/15 7:08    19B2569194BB4471E0530390300A15A6
```

Comment: What encoding does your CSV file use? Can you post a sample CSV file for testing?

Comment: @PeterGibson I just added the first two lines above, and due to formatting, I deleted some column names. Also, i just checked that the encoding of this CSV file is "charset=unknown-8bit"

Comment: @PeterGibson I just converted the file to utf-8 encoding, and it worked. Thanks